# Probability of sequential order of weighted group

Tags: probability

Let us assume that on average 4 fruit trees produce the following number of fruits per growing season ...

| Fruit |  | Fruits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | (Fa) | 100 |
| Orange | (Fo) | 80 |
| Lemon | (Fl) | 70 |
| Grapefruit | (Fg) | 50 |

How to calculate the probability which will produce the most (P(Fa.1), P(Fo.1), P(Fl.1) and P(Fg.1).  Is it as simple as P(Fa.1) = 100/(100+80+70+50) = 0.33 and likewise for the others giving P(Fo.1)= 0.27, P(Fl.1) = 0.23 and P(Fg.1) = 0.17?  If so how would you go on to calculate the probability that each produces the second most fruits eg P(Fa.2) and so on, then 3rd most and finally the least fruits so you end up with a table like This ...

|  | Apple | Orange | Lemon | Grapefruit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Most Fruits | P(Fa.1) | P(Fo.1) | P(Fl.1) | P(Fg.1) |
| 2nd Most Fruits | P(Fa.2) | P(Fo.2) | P(Fl.2) | P(Fg.2) |
| 3rd Most Fruits | P(Fa.3) | P(Fo.3) | P(Fl.3) | P(Fg.3) |
| Least Fruits | P(Fa.4) | P(Fo.4) | P(Fl.4) | P(Fg.4) |

I have spent days searching for an answer on the Internet!  :(  Maybe it's not possible.

Comment: Interesting problem, although it's off topic here; it's better suited to stats.stackexchange.com. The general topic is called "order statistics". In order to make headway, you'll have to assume a distribution for apples, oranges, etc.; it turns out just knowing the average numbers isn't enough.

Comment: @ Robert Dodier by "you'll have to assume a distribution for apples, oranges, etc." do you mean make some assumption for a histogram distribution for each of the fruits.  I can't product a factual one so if I assume one what would I do with it?!  :)

Comment: Right, I assume you'll have to make some assumptions, or find some publication (perhaps in the field of horticulture or botany) that talks about it. If you need to make some assumptions, that's okay, just clearly state what you have assumed. Then what you will do is compute conditional probabilities, namely P(apple greater than others), P(orange greater than others), etc. This becomes more interesting for 2nd or 3rd greatest, e.g. P(apple is third greatest) means exactly P(apple is greater than orange and orange is least and the other two are greater than apple, etc.)

Comment: Given specific distributions, it is possible to work out those conditional probabilities; you should at least try it. But a simpler and maybe just as good solution is to estimate the probabilities by simulation: sample a number of fruits from your assume distributions, and count up how many times the apple is greatest, how many times the lemon, the orange, etc.